# Cordova CLI android path

Tags: javascript, cordova

l'm getting a error from cordova cmd i don't know why and all path are right

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/jb/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/jb/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.3
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you have JDK 8 or at least no path pointing to JDK 8 dir

Add a `JAVA_HOME` variable and give it the path like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` (Your JDK home dir)